# Trying to use transparent image but a black background is being added

Tags: android, background, transparency

I have a transparent image in my drawable folder and I'm trying to send it using an Intent. The image loads and sends just fine but it's no longer transparent and has a black bacground attached to it. This is how I'm sending the image

```
Intent localIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND");      
localIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,         
Uri.parse("android.resource://com.t4t.stickerwhatsapp/" + videoDetails.get(pos)));
localIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(localIntent,111);
```

videoDetails.get(pos) is the id of the image in the drawable folder. Why is it adding a black background to my images?

Edit: It turns out my phone is adding the black bg to all transparent images that I receive it's not the code adding it before it sends.

Comment: setType to image/png and try

Comment: I was really hoping that would work lol but no dice it still has a black background.

Comment: May be after receiving the image, you can try to again set the background of image as transparent.

Comment: The only issue is I'm not really getting the image I'm only fetching the path to the image and then sending that to the intent. The intent is grabbing the image and sending it.

Comment: I might be an idiot...When sending to my phone I was seeing a black bg. When sending to my computers email it looks fine. I'm wondering if it's sending as transparent but my device is adding the bg for some reason. Just confirmed that's what's happening.

Comment: Check which theme you are using. I am guessing you are using Theme.Black. Change the background color layout in which you are displaying the image. See if the color changes from black to your newly changed color

Comment: Have you got any solution here?

Comment: Nope never figured it out

Answer (score 0):

You should get the drawable out of the resources by using the resources available from getResources().

I recommend you use:

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image);
```

The id of an image may change and keeping tabs on it is a bad idea. If you must do this, instead you may use:

```
getResources().getIdentifier("image", "drawable","package_name");
```

If the image is still not transparent, I might try setting the drawables background color using Color.Transparent. It can be a number of issues, especially if on the other end the drawable is getting processed.

Comment: Once I convert it to a bitmap how do I then send it in the intent?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my phone is adding the black bg to all transparent images that I receive it's not the code adding it before it sends.